# Keyboard shortcut to exit matlab command prompt?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, matlab

I've been using the command-line matlab interface (`matlab --nodesktop`) a lot lately.

When I want to jump out of matlab and back to my bash shell, my instinct is to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. I guess the bash and python shortcuts conditioned me to automatically do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Problem is, matlab wants me to type `exit` instead of hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Is there a way to convince matlab to let me exit the command line interface by doing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>?

Comment: Please check whether the given answer helps, and accept it if so. Otherwise elaborate on the problem as it is not desirable to leave the question open.

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked and it is indeed possible to exit matlab with a hotkey.
The default setting is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> but of course you can change this as described on the [Mathworks blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/09/28/configurable-keyboard-shortcuts-have-arrived).

Setting it is most easily done without `-nodesktop`, but the hotkeys do work in `nodesktop` mode.

Comment: haven't looked at the mathworks blog yet, but `Ctrl+Q` doesn't seem to work using the default configuration.

Comment: Perhaps the hotkeys differ per version or OS, it should only take you 2 mins to check the blog and see whether you can make it work.

Comment: It's been a while since this was asked, but in 2018 `Ctrl+Q` still doesn't work for me when using `-nodesktop` in Ubuntu Linux. The same shortcut does work fine on the same system when using the GUI. I would love a solution for this as well but outside of a text-expander utility or other outside-Matlab hack, there doesn't seem to be one.